# get rid of scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

I am trying to make a simple tool-tip. Problem is when i click on bottom buttons, tool-tip brings page scroll bar. In that case i want tool-tip should **Aligned to the bottom of the page** with out scroll bar.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<div class="pop">Text</div>
</div>

 JS:
$(".main").on("click", "button", function(){
  var top = $(this).offset().top;
  $(".pop").show(".pop");
  $(".pop").css("top", top)

})

$(".pop").click(function(){
  $(this).css("display", "none")
})
```

Sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEdRoY

Comment: I couldn't see any scroll-bar.

Comment: Click on last "click me" button. May be you have large desktop. I have increased the height of tooltip. Now it would be visible.

Comment: buddy i hv given JavaScript demo, let me know about it!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to calculate the height using JavaScript.

The reason it is not possible in CSS is because of the clash between fixed `height`, `top` offset and `bottom` offset.

But you can use the following code to calculate the overflow and make a switch based on scenario.

```
if(($("html").height() - (top + 400)) > 0) {
    //set top offset
} else {
    //set bottom offset
}
```

Based on the condition you can either choose to set `top` or `bottom` to avoid the clash.

[Here is the demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPgyra)

If you want to calculate the `height` along with the margins then use [`outerHeight`](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

Comment: i appreciate u tried, but it didn't work. your demo is not working.

Comment: you still get a scroll bar in my demo ?

Comment: fly out heights get cut off from the bottom. It goes inside the page. I want to make it align with the bottom without scroll bar

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: I've tested the codepen in Chrome, FF and IE. Which browser are you using ?

Comment: The height I was reading was returning 0 when the popup was hidden. Try this codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPgyra

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can try below `CSS` class to your `popup` window:

```
.pop{
    height:200px; 
    width:200px;
    border:red solid 1px; 
    position:fixed; 
    display:none;
 }
```

And it hides DIV's part which is outer the screen.
If you don't wanna lose it, then as you said not able to achieve with only `CSS`. JavaScript is required! what I had in my project as,

[**Example of floating tool tip**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/wyhQN/106/)

Comment: Cant make it's height auto, .pop would contain form fields so its height will gonna increase.

Comment: position fixed is not the solution, it will cut the popup from the bottom. It is not possible with CSS.

Comment: yup @Praveen, now tried with JavaScript, hope this will help!